# Decoding a string to get the value "Indsætning"

Tags: c#, encoding, urlencode

I have a string (C# code) that looks as follows:

```
string s = "IndsÃ¦tning";
```

It is encoded in some way that I am not sure of.

I'd like to decode it so that I get the following string:

```
Indsætning
```

I have tried with

```
string s1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s);
string s2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
```

However, I don't get the string that I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string? You don't want to use either of those decoding options. You need to change the character encoding. Those methods will simply replace characters that aren't allowed in URLs and HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the string to bytes and then using the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to get the `UTF-8` string representation.

```
string s = "IndsÃ¦tning";

byte[] sBytes = s.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sBytes);
```

Edit - As mentioned in the comments, this assumes that the string being converted is of a particular encoding ([Latin-1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e6/index.htm) in this case). Therefore, it won't necessarily work for all strings, unless you know that they've all been encoded into the same format.

Comment: Well, that assumes that the string is in Latin-1 encoding, which in this case it is, but you should make that assumption explicit...